# How do I set up and ftp server with a linux machine so that other people can use the files?

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to set up an ftp server for our lab at work. I have some files on my computer and I need the people in my office to be able to access them with a link.  I know this is very broad, but how do I do this?

The most important part for me is knowing the ip address of the ftp server.

I have an ubuntu distribution

Comment: Please provide us with which Linux distribution you are using in your lab this will help us to narrow down best possible ftp servers.
The ip address will be the address you currently have on your machine, you can get it by running the following command.

/sbin/ifconfig

Answer (score 0):

What particular distribution of Linux are you using to do this?

Ubuntu has some [very good documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html) on how to setup an FTP server, but the steps required will vary a bit between distros. If you update your question to include what distribution you're using, I can update my answer with some more specific / relevant information.

If your only problem is knowing the IP address of the server, then the command `ifconfig` will provide you with this information. Note that this command may need to be run as root or with `sudo`.